# Error (104): Connection reset by peer - Linux RHEL, Apache HTTP Server and IIS server

Tags: linux, apache, iis, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have Linux RHEL server and I installed Apached HTTP proxy server on that. I have second Windows server and it has .net application installed on IIS server.

I am using proxy server to redirect calls to IIS server. But almost after 30 min, getting below error on HTTP error_log

[error] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] (104)Connection reset by peer: proxy: error reading status line from remote server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx (IIS Server IP)
[error] [client xxx.xxx.xx.xxx] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /web/url/2920357

I kept all default settings in httpd.conf file and added below supporting setting to redirect the request

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
          ServerName server_name
          ProxyRequests     off
          ProxyPreserveHost on
          ProxyPass / http://IIS_SERVER_IP/
          ProxyPassReverse / http://IIS_SERVER_IP/

          <Proxy *>
               Order deny,allow
               Allow from all
          </Proxy></VirtualHost>
```

Please let me know if there are any additional settings I have to make in proxy server.

Found similar kind of issue [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770), but they don't have provided any solution.

Answer (score 1):

On the link that you provided, i found possible [reason](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770#c17) and a  [workaround](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770#c29) for it.

Workaround:

Make sure you have mod_env enabled and set this to httpd.conf

> SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
>
> SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1

Did you try it?